# Settings for a github actions yml file: Create Issue Branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using github and github actions.
With the actions [Create Issue Branch](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch), it's possible to automatically generate a branch when a user is assigned to the issue/ticket.

This works perfectly! When I have the standard file from the [documentation](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch?tab=readme-ov-file#option-2-configure-github-action): `.github/workflows/create_branch.yml`:

```
on:
  # The issue.opened event below is only needed for the "immediate" mode.
  # The issue.assigned event below is only needed for the default ("auto") mode.
  issues:
    types: [ opened, assigned ]
  # The issue_comment.created event below is only needed for the ChatOps mode.
  issue_comment:
    types: [ created ]
  # The pull_request events below are only needed for pull-request related features.
  pull_request:
    types: [ opened, closed ]

jobs:
  create_issue_branch_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create Issue Branch
      uses: robvanderleek/create-issue-branch@main
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

However I need to pass in the setting `branchName: '${issue.number}-${issue.title}'` to make a custom branchName .. So far I havn't been able to find out where.. And in my attempt to pass in the setting, I broke the action.

Where should I put the variable `branchName` in the `.yml' file?

Comment: You have to put that into `.github/issue-branch.yml`, not the workflow file.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you! Please add a submit as an answer if you want the green tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This action doesn't take any inputs provided with `with` (see their [`action.yml` file](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch/blob/e18abdf399bbc9892c9a3ab1b32adf639767c161/action.yml)).

Instead, if you want to modify default behaviour, the action checks for a file `.github/issue-branch.yml`, and *that* is where  you can set the branch name convention like

```yaml
branchName: '${issue.number}-${issue.title}'
```

Notice that you have the indentation wrong in your snippet: `uses` must not be less indented than `name` for a step.

And, not to take away from the creator of the action, but creating a branch seems to be simple enough to do it directly in a `run` step, something like

```yaml
name: Create branch on assignment

on:
  issues:
    types:
      - assigned

jobs:
  createbranch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1

      - name: Create issue branch
        env:
          number: ${{ github.event.issue.number }}
          title: ${{ github.event.issue.title }}
        run: |
          title=${title// /-}
          branchname=$number-${title,,}
          git switch -c "$branchname"
          git config --global user.name 'github-actions'
          git config --global user.email \
              '41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'
          git push -u origin "$branchname"
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your current workflow file, to add a custom `branchName`, I believe you need to modify the `Create Issue Branch` step to include a [`with`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idwith) section where you define `branchName` like this:

```yaml
jobs:
  create_issue_branch_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Create Issue Branch
        uses: robvanderleek/create-issue-branch@main
        with:
          branchName: '${issue.number}-${issue.title}'
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

In a similar setup I have, `${issue.number}` and `${issue.title}` dynamically insert the issue number and title into the branch name.

Comment: weird, now the action runs but the branchName does not reflect the setting provided. The action adds "issue" to the front of the branchName. I have a issue with title "test" and id "39". The branchName created with the action is " issue-39-test". Seems like the action is faulty, or the yml settings did not go through

Comment: Hmm, I see. I’ll suggest you read through the documentation for the action. I’m sure you’re close. There’s most likely just a minor change to be made. https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch?tab=readme-ov-file#branch-names.  I also modified my answer above, but try to read through the branch names section in this link I shared. Sure it’ll help.

Comment: The syntax is `${{ ... }}` for expressions, not `${ ... }`.

Comment: Also, the action does not take any inputs, see [here](https://github.com/robvanderleek/create-issue-branch/blob/main/action.yml). It relies on a separate config file.